# gdm3 session manager stopped after a Debian Stretch update

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, gdm3

After an update the boot to between the GRUB menu and the session manager gdm3. For recovery mode I installed other managers and they all work, but I like gdm3. I already used google but for the keywords I did not find anything that would help me.

Comment: You are not alone. I have this issue on _every_ Debian install after the latest update. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=898074
And https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=897631

Comment: This bug is solved in kernel `4.9.88-1+deb9u1`. Do a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to fix!